# How to combine multiple arrays (that represent columns of data) into a nested/jagged array (or even a 2D) array

Tags: c#, .net

I have a program that I'm writing to extract certain data from various excel spreadsheet.

The process so far is:

for each spreadsheet identified:

-read in the data as a multidimensional array using interop excel (Even though it is slow, it is the best choice due to all of the different file formats I need to read in)

```
    Sample: object[,] cellValues = (object[,])range.Value2;
```

-Identify the columns that I actually need and what order I need them in.  This is stored in a jagged array of bytes:

```
    byte[][] targetColumns
```

-THe jagged array essentially is (columnIndexFromSpreadsheet, preferredColumnOrder) e.g. if the first column in the spreadsheet should be read in as column 10 it would be (1, 10)

-I sort the jagged array by the preferred column order (that way I can just loop through the array in that order and extract those columns):

```
        public static byte[][] SortTargetColumns(byte[][] targetColumns)
        {
            return targetColumns.OrderBy(x => x.Skip(1).First()).ToArray();
        }
```

-I then extract that column by creating an array from that column index of the multidimensional array.  This is the method that is called:

```
    public static object[]  ExtractColumn(object[,] dataArray ,byte columnIndex)
    {
        return Enumerable.Range(ArrayIndexStart, dataArray.GetLength(0)).Select(x => dataArray[x, columnIndex]).ToArray();
    }

    Usage:

    array = ExtractColumn(dataArray, (byte) colIndex);
```

Now I am trying to piece these extracted arrays back together to make it readable.  I will need to do some manipulation on some of the columns and then write to a text file after consolidating.  The only problem is that I have no idea how to do this correctly.  I have tried the following methods but continue to get a null reference exception:

```
// Get Row Count of dataArray
int rowCount = dataArray.GetLength(0);

// Create List to store extracted arrays
List<object[]> extractedDataList = new List<object[]>();

// Loop through target columns and extract the column as an array
for (byte colIndex = 1; colIndex <= targetColumns.Length + 1; colIndex++)
{
    object[] array = ExtractColumn(dataArray, (byte) colIndex);
    extractedDataList.Add(array);
}

// Create jagged array
object[][] extractedDataArray = new object[rowCount][] ; 


for(int i = 0; i < extractedDataArray.GetLength(0); i++)
{
    List<object> row = new List<object>();
    for (int j = 0; j < extractedDataList.Count; j++)
    {
        row.Add(extractedDataList[j][i].ToString());
        //extractedDataArray[i][j] = extractedDataList[j][i].ToString(); <-- null reference
    }
    extractedDataArray[i] = row.ToArray();
}
```

I'm at a loss of what else to try to put these column arrays back in a form that I can easily work with.  Any and all tips/recommendations would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you get confused like this, break the problem down into small pieces, and use meaningful names.

Let's say you have an array of columns, each of which has one element per row. That might be declared like this:

```
object[][] columns;
```

First, let's get the row and column counts:

```
var columnCount = columns.Length;
var rowCount = columns[0].Length;
```

Now write a small [local function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/local-functions) to accept a row and column index and return the right cell. In case not all of your columns have the same number of rows, you can include a boundary check and just return null if a cell isn't there.

```
object Getter(int row, int col)
{
    bool outOfBounds = (row >= columns[col].Length);
    return outOfBounds ? null : columns[col][row];
}
```

Now all we have to do is iterate over the rows to create the inner arrays:

```
object[][] target = new object[rowCount][]
for (int row = 0; row < rowCount; row++)
{
    target[row] = new object[columnCount];
}
```

And add in the code that uses the getter to populate the cells:

```
object[][] target = new object[rowCount][];
for (int row = 0; row < rowCount; row++)
{
    target[row] = new object[columnCount];
    for (int col = 0; col < columnCount; col++)
    {
        var cellValue = Getter(row, col);
        target[row][columnCount] = cellValue;
    }
}
```

All together, it is simple to read:

```
var columnCount = columns.Length;
var rowCount = columns[0].Length;

object Getter(int row, int col)
{
    bool outOfBounds = (row >= columns[col].Length);
    return outOfBounds ? null : columns[col][row];
}

object[][] target = new object[rowCount][];

for (int row = 0; row < rowCount; row++)
{
    target[row] = new object[columnCount];
    for (int col = 0; col < columnCount; col++)
    {
        var cellValue = Getter(row, col);
        target[row][columnCount] = cellValue;
    }
}
```